# Azure Storage access from Azure web site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a blob storage tree display built into a website running happily from the Visual Studio 2015 iisexpress. When the files are uploaded to an Azure web site, the page with the storage tree causes a browser error "Too many redirects". Is there anything different because it's running on Azure? I'm an Azure newbie.

Here is the code doing the connection

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
@using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
@using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
@using System.Web.Configuration;
@using System.Text;
@using System.Linq;

@{
    string accountName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageAccountName"];
    string accountKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageAccessKey"];
    string rootContainer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageRootContainer"];

    try {
        StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName,accountKey);
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds,useHttps :true);

        CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containerList = client.ListContainers(rootContainer);

        foreach(var container in containerList) {    
            var blobCount = container.ListBlobs().Count();
            HtmlString listing = getContainerDirectories(container.ListBlobs());

            @Html.Raw(listing); 
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        <p>@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("[Global] Sorry try again")</p>
    }
}
```

TIA

Comment: You need to post some code, it seems the site redirects you to a page that redirects and so on ... . So it is probably have some configuration error in your logon page or error page. Check when you do a redirect and your loginUrl configuration etc. I guess when you find the code that redirects you, you will have the answer on how to fix it. The to many redirects is 100% not related with the fact you are using windows-azure-storage.

Comment: The code doesn't cause a redirect in VS so I reckon the code is good. Only when run from Azure is there a problem. It's using nuget installed packages: WindowsAzure.Storage, Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core, Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies and Microsoft.Azure.Common. So the question is, what's the difference between running a site on an external web server and running the same site on Azure wrt accessing Azure Blob Storage. As far as I'm concerned there shouldn't be any. Happy to be proved wrong, hence the question.

Comment: Can you trace the requests through something like Fiddler?

Comment: Just added the code doing the connection. Not used Fiddler before, will try.

Comment: Fiddler just shows me what's going on between the browser and the site, not what's going on between the site and the storage. What returned in the text view for each reload is:-
"ac
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://somesite.net/en-gb/login/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

0"

Comment: @peer You were correct. I removed the login restriction and the blob storage contents were displayed correctly. Focus now shifted to the login script.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

From comment2answer: You need to post some code, it seems the site redirects you to a page that redirects and so on ... . So it is probably have some configuration error in your logon page or error page. Check when you do a redirect and your loginUrl configuration etc. I guess when you find the code that redirects you, you will have the answer on how to fix it. The to many redirects is 100% not related with the fact you are using windows-azure-storage