# Azure:limit the access of ARM PaaS services to certain storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have a security question related to Azure that I could really do with some guidance on the art of what is possible.

I would like to know if it is possible to restrict what services can be called (i.e what storage account endpoints can be used to write data to) from PaaS services such as service fabric or web apps (ASE). i.e. if I have a web app that writes to storage and someone maliciously altered the code to write to a third party storage account on Azure; is this something I could mitigate in advance by saying this application (i.e. this web app or this SF cluster) can only talk to a particular set of storage accounts or a particular database. So that even if the code was changed to talk to another storage account, it wouldnt be able to. I.e can I explicitly define as part of an environment what storage items an application can talk to; Is this something that is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Storage access from Azure web site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157125/azure-storage-access-from-azure-web-site)

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage Accounts have Access Keys and Shared Access Keys that are used to authenticate REST calls to read / write data to them. Your app will be able to perform read / write operations against the Azure Storage Account that it has an access key and connection string for that it uses to connect to it with.

It's not possible to set any kind of firewall rule on an Azure App Service app to prevent it from communicating with certain internet or Azure endpoints. You can set NSG firewall rules with App Service Environment, but you still can only either open or close access; not restrict on certain DNS names or IP Addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look for a mitigation to this threat in the way applications are deployed, connection strings are managed and code is deployed:

- Use Azure Role Based Access control to limit access to the resource in Azure, so unauthorized persons cannot modify deployments
- Use a secure way of managing your source code. Remember it is not on the PaaS service, because that only holds the binaries.
- Use SAS tokens for application access to storage accounts, not the full access keys. For example, a SAS key could be given write access, not read or list access to a storage account.
- If, as a developer, you don't trust the person managing the application deployment, you could even consider signing your application parameters/connection strings. That only protects against tampering though, not against extraction of the connection string.